# Hibernate Projections / Lazy Loading for non required 1 to 1 Mappings

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have the following 2 classes (trimmed down for this post)

```
public class ApplicationVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3314933694797958587L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "application")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnore
    private ApplicationHomeScreenVO applicationHomeScreen;

...
...
... 
}


public class ApplicationHomeScreenVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9158898930601867545L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JoinColumn(name="application_id")
    @JsonProperty("application")
    protected ApplicationVO application;    

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am trying to load an applicationById wuthout loading the applicationHomeScreen
Unfortunately the lazy loading doesnt seem to be working. I have looked at other posts and they recommend setting the option=false flag on the @OneToOne annotation but unfortunately, applicationHomeScreen can be optional

I am now trying to use projections but that is not working either for me either

When I call the following method

```
 public ApplicationVO findApplicationById(Integer applicationId) {

        Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(ApplicationVO.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", applicationId));

        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("applicationHomeScreen"), "applicationHomeScreen"))
              .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ApplicationVO.class));

        ApplicationVO applicationVO = (ApplicationVO) criteria.uniqueResult();

        return applicationVO;
    }
```

I get the stack trace

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:754)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:402)
    at com.dao.database.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl.findApplicationById(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:349)
```

Can anyone recommend an approach I can use to either 
a) get lazy loading working properly for one to one mappings where the association is not required
b) get projections working so I dont need to load any child associations if they are not needed

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Just wondering if anyone knows how I can acheive this with projections?

Comment: Might be it's of some help : http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/one-to-one-and-lazy-vs-eager-loading.html

Comment: Do you really need a bidirectional connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option is to follow these steps:

1. Add [@LazyToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyToOne.html) to the one-to-one association:

   ```
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "application")
   @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
   @JsonIgnore
   @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
   private ApplicationHomeScreenVO applicationHomeScreen;
   ```
2. Configure [bytecode enhancement](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-bytecode-enhancement/)

Answer (score 1):

Optional `@OneToOne` relationships cannot be lazy because the non-owning side of the relationship does not now whether the child exists(optional) - Hibernate doesn't know whether to put a proxy object or `null`. There are several workarounds for this. This [link](http://justonjava.blogspot.com/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html) has detailed explanation on some workarounds

Comment: I saw these options already cheers-  some of them are not appealing. Should i be able to limit the results with projections?

Comment: You can use result transforming as you tried and select  only custom columns from db and then return this custom bean, but that's another thing(you'll not be working with actual entity - it is suitable for some cases)

Comment: yeah i know what you mean. That didnt work for me unfortunately with my mapping - would you know why?